# Running resize logo script on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a custom logo shrink on a website, but I'm doing something wrong and can't locate the mistake. Maybe you can give a small advice.

So what I already did:

1.Child theme with style.css, functions.php, assets/js/my_shrinker.js

2.I added a function to load my-shrinker.js in functions.php

```
function shrinker() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_shrinker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/my_shrinker.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shrinker' );
```

3.Added this code to perform shrink when scrolling in my-shrinker.js

```
function my_shrinker() { 
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            d = document.getElementsByTagName("kad-header-left");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            d.className += " shrinkedlogoyo";
        } else {
            d.classList.remove("shrinkedlogoyo");
        }
        })
}
```

The script should add "shrinkedlogo" class to the kad-header-left div, which has this css

```
.shrinkedlogoyo { display: block !important; position: absolute !important; left: 8% !important; top: 2px !important; width: 45px !important; height: 45px !important; }
```

But, well, this ain't happening and I'm not getting any error. Can you give me a good advice?

Website is http://arthome17.ru

Comment: Has my answer helped you ?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear it ! So please remember to validate my answer. ; ) Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script "my-shrinker.js" is not called correctly.

> http://arthome17.ru/wp-content/themes/virtue_premium/assets/js/my-shrinker.js?ver=1.0.0

returns a 404.

This is because of `get_template_directory_uri()` that looking for the script in the parent theme.

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead with your child theme.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**
Since the new error in the console (SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters)

I will suggest you to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` properties and review you syntax.

**RE-EDIT**

If you want your script runs on page ready, you'll have to write something like this :

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() { 
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300;
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            $(".kad-header-left").addClass("shrinkedlogoyo");
        } else {
            $(".kad-header-left").removeClass("shrinkedlogoyo");
        }
    });
});
```

**Add jsfiddle**

Here a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/tok9bksp/) of the working script. Good luck !

Comment: Hi Adrien, 

I tried your suggestion and updated the code in my question. Though it doesn't perform the required action. No class added to the div. Do I have to execute it a different way?

Comment: You have an error now in the console : `SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters`

Comment: Also, when the function `my_shrinker` is called ?

Comment: I fixed the console error by changing "-" in names to "_" - error disappeared. How do I call functions? I think it's not called at all, if it's not called in my above code.

Comment: It's also a good idea the remove the space from the child theme folder. Well done !

Comment: Or you could just call the function at the end of the js script after the last line of the function : `my_shrinker();`

Comment: tried it back and forth. when adding your code it says addclass or removeclass is not a function. otherwise it says to remove ) at the end. can't find whats wrong.

Comment: Ok, so, try to put this on first line of the js script : `$ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: I re-edit the last part. Use the code as it is. You got another syntax error in the console. This new script shall solve this.

Comment: I had to remove one ";" from the pre-last line. now it says my_shrinker(); is undefined and rest seems to be working.

Comment: there is no "my_shrinker()" function in the new code I post. Use it as it is.

Comment: Added a working jsfiddle the answer. Here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/tok9bksp/  Your code works well !

Comment: Nice ! I see you got it to work on your website. Congratulation !